# add a number of months to Datetime in Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create a module can do this : inputdate = "27 Feb 2017", nomonths = 2, so outputdate must be "27 April 2017". inputdate and nomonths are 2 fields we have to fill in, and ouputdate is just a "read-only" field in odoo.

```
class DateGenerate(models.Model):
     _name = "studentmanagement.dategenerate"

    inputdate = fields.Date()
    nomonths = fields.Integer(required=True)
    outputdate = fields.Date(readonly=True)

    @api.onchange('inputdate','nomonths')
    def add_month(self):
       for record in self:
          dt = fields.Datetime.to_string(record.inputdate)
          inpYear = datetime.strptime(dt,"%Y")
          inpMonth = datetime.strptime(dt,"%m")
          inpDay = datetime.strptime(dt,"%d")
          outYear = inpYear + int((inpMonth + record.nomonths - 1)/12)
          outMonth = (inpMonth + record.nomonths - 1) % 12 + 1
          record.outputdate = datetime.date(outMonth, inpDay, outYear)
```

[image: XML]

I write the code based on the sources and explanations on the internet, but it does not work and causes the error :
[image]

I read the code and direction from these links

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/fields.py#L1504

Answer (score 0):

To add/take months onto a date/datetime object I would suggest using the python package: `dateutil.relativedelta`. http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

basic usage:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print date.today() + relativedelta(months=+3)
print datetime.today() + relativedelta(months=+3)

print date.today() - relativedelta(months=+3)
print datetime.today() - relativedelta(months=+3)
```

Your question references both `datetime` and `date` objects so have included examples for both.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we do this
"record.outputdate = record.inputdate + relativedelta(months=+record.nomonths)". record is one row in self of odoo database, but it causes the error :"File "dateutil\relativedelta.pyc", line 247, in __radd__
TypeError: unsupported type for add operation"

Comment: Is your record.inputdate a python date or datetime object? and is your record.nomonths an integer?

Comment: nomonths is an Integer, but record.inputdate is a date object in ODOO, not python. So I guess this is the error, but I don't know how to add/get dates in odoo.

Comment: youll have to convert your odoo date to a python date. you can probably just do a substring (slice) of your odoo date. py_date = date(yyyy, mm, dd)